# Php Array key=> value searching

Tags: php

---

HI I am fairly new to php.

I have an array

$arr = array(0 => array('GID'=>1,'groupname'=>"cat1",'members'=>array(0=>array('mid'=>11,'mname'=>'wwww'),1=>array('mid'=>12,'mname'=>'wswww'))),
             1 => array('GID'=>2,'groupname'=>"cat2",'members'=>array(0=>array('mid'=>13,'mname'=>'gggwwww'),1=>array('mid'=>14,'mname'=>'wvvwww'))),
             2 => array('GID'=>3,'groupname'=>"cat1",'members'=>array(0=>array('mid'=>15,'mname'=>'wwddsww')),1=>array('mid'=>16,'mname'=>'wwwdddw')));

```
      ie...,I have GID,groupname,mid(member id),mname(member name).I want to insert a new mid and mname into a group if it is already in the array ,if it is not exists then create a new subarray with these elements..I also need to check a member id(mid) is also present.........................I used the code but its not working fine............. if (!empty($evntGroup)) {


            foreach ($evntGroup as $k => $group) {

                if ($group['GID'] == $group_id) {
                    foreach($group as $j=> $mem){

                    if($mem['mid'] == $mem_id){

                        unset($evntGroup[$k]['members'][$j]['mid']);
                        unset($evntGroup[$k]['members'][$j]['mname']);
                    }
                    else{


                    $evntGroup[$k]['members'][] = array(
                        'mid' => $mem_id,
                        'mname' => $mem_name);

                    }}
                } else {


                    $evntGroup[] = array(
                        'GID' => $group_id,
                        'groupname' => $Group['event_group_name'],
                        'members' => array(
                            0 => array(
                                'mid' => $mem_id,
                                'mname' => $mem_name
                            )
                        )
                    );

                }

            }
        } else {

            $evntGroup[$i]['GID'] = $group_id;
            $evntGroup[$i]['groupname'] = $Group['event_group_name'];
            $evntGroup[$i]['members'][] = array(
                'mid' => $mem_id,
                'mname' => $mem_name);
            $i++;

        }
```

Comment: Its the `mid` is under `members` which has its own ID  ... What wold your expected result be like of `'GID'=>1` is modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form of a function, the easiest solution will look something like this:

```
function isGidInArray($arr, $val) {
    foreach($arr as $cur) {
        if($cur['GID'] == $val)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You've updated your question to specify what you want to do if the specified GID is found, but that's just a trivial addition to the loop:

```
function doSomethingIfGidInArray($arr, $val) {
    foreach($arr as $cur) {
        if($cur['GID'] == $val) {
            doSomething();
            break; //Assuming you only expect one instance of the passed value - stop searching after it's found
        }
    }
}
```

There is unfortunately no native PHP array function that will retrieve the same index of every array within a parent array. I've often wanted such a thing.

Comment: ie...,I have GID,groupname,mid(member id),mname(member name).I want to insert a new mid and mname into a group if it is already in the array ,if it is not exists then create a new subarray with these elements..I also need to check a member id(mid) is also present.........................I used the code but its not working fine.............

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will match if GID equals 3:

```
foreach( $arr as $item ) {
  if( $item['GID'] == 3 ) {
     // matches
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the code

```
function updateByGid(&$array,$gid,$groupname,$mid,$mname) {
    //For each element of the array
    foreach ($array as $ii => $elem) {
        //If GID has the same value
        if ($elem['GID'] == $gid) {
            //Insert new member
            $array[$ii]['members'][]=array(
                        'mid'=>$mid,
                        'mname'=>$mname);
            //Found!
            return 0;
        }
    }       
    //If not found, create new
    $array[]=array(
            'GID'=>$gid,
            'groupname'=>$groupname,
            'members'=>array(
                0=>array(
                    'mid'=>$mid,
                    'mname'=>$mname
                )
            )
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have GID,groupname,mid(member id),mname(member name).I want to insert a new mid and mname into a group if it is already in the array ,if it is not exists then create a new subarray with these elements

Comment: and ... What is the problem? What's missing?

Comment: then, do  you want to look for a mid and mname inside a GID and if you don't find it, insert a new member? Do you have the GID which you want to use or Do you have to create a new one (if it doesn't exist)?

I think the solution is easy, but I don't quite understand you